# I have a http post request but now when trying to run the app the main activity crashes oncreate

Tags: android, kotlin, okhttp

Im trying to get a post a json with a header to an api. But when i run the program in crashes on creation on my test device.

Ive tried to look around the forums but nothing about what errors from http3 are causing this.

private val client = OkHttpClient()

```
@Throws(Exception::class)
fun fetchJson() {
    val formBody = FormBody.Builder()
        //json im trying to post

        .addEncoded("body", "{\n" +
                "  \"dateTime\": \"2018-06-21T09:18:23.283-07:00\",\n" +
                "  \"apiOptions\": [\n" +
                "    \"ALLOWPARTIALAUTH\"\n" +
                "  ],\n" +
                "  \"amount\": {\n" +
                "    \"cashback\": 20,\n" +
                "    \"surcharge\": 5,\n" +
                "    \"tax\": 15,\n" +
                "    \"tip\": 20,\n" +
                "    \"total\": 160\n" +
                "  },\n" +
                "  \"card\": {\n" +
                "    \"entryMode\": \"M\",\n" +
                "    \"expirationDate\": 1230,\n" +
                "    \"number\": \"4321000000001119\",\n" +
                "    \"present\": \"N\",\n" +
                "    \"securityCode\": {\n" +
                "      \"indicator\": \"1\",\n" +
                "      \"value\": \"333\"\n" +
                "    }\n" +
                "  },\n" +
                "  \"clerk\": {\n" +
                "    \"numericId\": 1576\n" +
                "  },\n" +
                "  \"customer\": {\n" +
                "    \"addressLine1\": \"65 Easy St\",\n" +
                "    \"firstName\": \"John\",\n" +
                "    \"lastName\": \"Smith\",\n" +
                "    \"postalCode\": \"65144\"\n" +
                "  },\n" +
                "  \"transaction\": {\n" +
                "    \"invoice\": \"192029\",\n" +
                "    \"notes\": \"Transaction notes are added here\",\n" +
                "    \"hotel\": {\n" +
                "      \"arrivalDateTime\": \"2018-06-18T15:39:01.594-07:00\",\n" +
                "      \"departureDateTime\": \"2018-06-21T09:18:23.283-07:00\",\n" +
                "      \"primaryChargeType\": 1,\n" +
                "      \"specialCode\": 1,\n" +
                "      \"additionalCharges\": {\n" +
                "        \"giftShop\": \"Y\",\n" +
                "        \"laundry\": \"Y\",\n" +
                "        \"miniBar\": \"Y\",\n" +
                "        \"other\": \"Y\",\n" +
                "        \"restaurant\": \"Y\",\n" +
                "        \"telephone\": \"Y\"\n" +
                "      },\n" +
                "      \"roomRates\": [\n" +
                "        {\n" +
                "          \"nights\": 2,\n" +
                "          \"rate\": 159.95\n" +
                "        },\n" +
                "        {\n" +
                "          \"nights\": 3,\n" +
                "          \"rate\": 125.38\n" +
                "        }\n" +
                "      ]\n" +
                "    },\n" +
                "    \"purchaseCard\": {\n" +
                "      \"customerReference\": \"D019D09309F2\",\n" +
                "      \"destinationPostalCode\": \"94719\",\n" +
                "      \"productDescriptors\": [\n" +
                "        \"Hamburger\",\n" +
                "        \"Fries\",\n" +
                "        \"Soda\",\n" +
                "        \"Cookie\"\n" +
                "      ]\n" +
                "    }\n" +
                "  },\n" +
                "  \"lighthouse\": {\n" +
                "    \"data\": \"eyJsaWdodGhvdXNlIjp7ImVtcGxveWVlaWQiOjEyMzQsImRldmljZWlkIjoiMTIzU0FCViJ9fQ==\"\n" +
                "  }\n" +
                "}")
        .build()
    val request = Request.Builder()
            //header information
        .url("https://utgapi.shift4test.com/api/rest/v1/transactions/sale")
        .addHeader("AccessToken","9EB227BC-A820-81CA-7607737B4809AA6E")
        .addHeader("CompanyName","PAWS")
        .addHeader("InterfaceName","ForwardPOS")
        .addHeader("InterfaceVersion","2.1")
        .post(formBody)
        .build()

    val response = client.newCall(request).execute()
    if (!response.isSuccessful) throw IOException("Unexpected code $response")

    System.out.println(response.body()?.string())
}
```

I expected the program to run and so it would talk to the api but it wont.

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: *application* has stopped

Comment: Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unexpected code Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=500, message=Resource Not Found: /api/rest/v1/transactions/sale, url=https://utg.shift4api.net/api/rest/v1/transactions/sale}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't make network requests on the main thread. Wrap it in an Async task.

Comment: could you link me to how i would be able to do this?